# DVD Writer doesn't read/write DVDs

Tags: windows, dvd, dvd-burning

I have a DVD reader/writer (about 2-3 years old) that used to read/write DVDs fine. Now when I put in a DVD it does nothing – and when I try to open it via *My Computer* it just freezes the window completely.

I also tried to boot of a DVD, but it just sits there, doing absolutely nothing. It's past warranty, so I dont mind opening it, but I would rather not have to buy another one.

However it seems to read/write CDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Device Manager to "uninstall the DVD drive, then restart windows.

1. Expand DVD/CD-ROM drives, then right click on your DVD drive and select "uninstall", close DM and restart.
2. If that fails to get it working, try [this fixit from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/cd_dvd_drive_problems/en-us)

If neither brings it back to life, it will need to be replaced.

[image]

Comment: Neither worked. But I guess I will just have to replace it.

Comment: Well maybe it just needs to be cleaned? This helped my MacBook (it couldn't read/write DVDs anymore).